# Восприятие перехода на новую строку в POST запросе

Tags: post

У меня есть HTML форма отправляющая данные POST запросом, но проблема в том что переходы на новую строку не воспринимаются, приходится если нужно перейти на новую строку писать `<br>`, а это как то не очень удобно. Не подскажите как бы так извернутся что бы воспринимались переходы на новую строку? (После отправки POST запроса данные отправляются в БД MySQL, и выводятся на другой странице.)

Comment: Функцию nl2br() посмотрите http://php.net/manual/ru/function.nl2br.php Хотя у вас в вопросе про язык ни чего не сказано.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

к каждому полю ввода добавьте атрибут style="display:block;"